# what privacy policy to disclose when using firebase for my app

Tags: firebase, flutter, policy, privacy

I made a flutter app that reads JASON data from firebase database, it is basically reference book made for education purposes. There is no passwords and no ability to store information from app to the database. It only works one direction: Firebase>>>app. What privacy policy I should disclose to my users?